# Should Obelus be really considered a division sign?

Tags: soft-question, notation, arithmetic

**Disclaimer:** This question is definitely not problem solving  but is for rectifying a doubt in history.

Recently I was researching on the historical significance of mathematical operators and their symbol origination.I started off reading about $+$ and $-$ symbols on Wikipedia, which sufficiently satisfied me with an explanation that $+$ in a simplification of Latin **"et"** (Comparable to **&**). The Egyptians' symbolism was unique too, with characteristics sign reversal to signify $+$ and $-$ sign.    (Although I believe Europe was smart enough not to adapt to that so as to make way for our $\sigma$)

Same was for our renowned minus sign $-$, the wikipedia provided convinceable information.

BUT. As I reached the division sign $\div$ (The $Obelus$) the reasoning went to trash. The Obelus actually signifies "The deceased".  Even though there is a statement saying:
$> Division may also be indicated by a horizontal line (fraction bar) or a slash. In ISO 80000-2-9.6 (about division) it says,

> "The symbol ÷ should not be used." In editing texts an obelus takes
>   the form of a dagger mark (†) and is used as a reference mark, or to
>   indicate that a person is deceased, and often used to indicate a
>   footnote."

Then my question is, since this $Obelus$ is also used as a symbol to represent subtraction (In Northern Europe), why are many schools in Asia still using this symbol as the one for fraction at the grass root level of education? **I do agree that we get accustomed to "/" as we grow up** , even then why promote usage of a symbol which itself acts as a significance of multiple other things at the schooling standards of second and third grade ?

I'm open to any convincing opinion upon this question.
Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe because the  ÷ symbol gives children in the second and third grade a better conceptual understanding of division before the standalone "/" symbol is introduced. As a kid I saw the dots in the obelus as kind of like place holders for the dividend and the divisor, then you learn that all you need is the "/" symbol and you're good to go.

Comment: I like your explanation for the dots as "place holders". I think a fundamental issue for teachers at the end of primary school and at the beginning of secondary school is to make the correspondance between the concept of fraction (rational), like $\tfrac{2}{5}$ and make understand the child that  $\tfrac{2}{5}=\tfrac{4}{10}...$, its decimal representation ($0.4$) and the division operation ("divide 2 by 5"),  allowing to switch from the fractional to the decimal representation, which is an algorithm. Thus, it is not abnormal to have, at a certain level of education, two symbols...